# Open a file using a system verb from batch file

Tags: batch-file

In Windows Explorer, I can right-click on a file and choose Edit (or other system actions/verbs) instead of Open.  Is it possible to do this from a cmd file?  I want to mimic right-clicking on a file and choosing Edit, i.e. the file should open in the program configured to handle the Edit verb.

Answer (score 1):

#### With PowerShell

```
PowerShell "(New-Object -com 'Shell.Application').ShellExecute('file.txt', '', '', 'edit')"
```

#### With VB Script

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.ShellExecute "file.txt", "", "", "edit"
```

See the [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [(Link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.